# How to assign a role to a user PHP

Tags: php, arrays, role

Well I have this form that adds user, admin.I've given to user the right to add another user but not add an admin or so!

```
$roles = db_fetch_all("role") ; 
$TabRoles = array(''=>'-- Choose --');
foreach($roles as $value)
{
    $TabRoles[$value['rid']] = $value['name'];
}
```

and with `print_array($TabRoles);` it displays me :

```
Array
(
    [] => -- Choose --
    [admin] => Admin
    [seo] => SEO
    [user] => User
)
```

The condistion is `if (user('rid') == 'admin'|'seo')` . I tried this :

```
foreach($roles as $value)
{
if (user('rid') == 'admin'|'seo')
    {
        $TabRoles[$value['rid']] = $value['name'];
    }else{

        $TabRoles[$value['rid']] = $value['name'][2];
    }
}
```

But it displays me the position "2" of the array !

```
Array
(
    [] => -- Choose --
    [admin] => m
    [seo] => O
    [user] => e
)
```

I want it to display like this :

```
Array
(
    [] => -- Choose --
    [user] => User
)
```

Any solution for this ? Many Thanks!

**The solution** : thanks to @DanFromGermany:

```
foreach($roles as $value)
{
if (user('rid') == 'admin' || user('rid') == 'seo')
    {
        $TabRoles[$value['rid']] = $value['name'];
    }elseif (user('rid') == $value['rid']){
 $TabRoles[$value['rid']] = $value['name'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (user('rid') == 'admin'|'seo')
```

`|` is a bitwise operator, but I guess you want a logical comparison here:

```
if (user('rid') == 'admin' || user('rid') == 'seo')
```

Explanation on using array brackets on strings:

```
$test = 'abcd';

echo $test[0]; // prints a
echo $test[1]; // prints b
echo $test[2]; // prints c
```

That's why you get only a letter instead of the element you want.

I think you are looking for something like:

```
foreach($roles as $value) {
    if (user('rid') == $value['rid'])
        $TabRoles[$value['rid']] = $value['name'];
    }
}
```

or

```
foreach($roles as $value) {
    $TabRoles[$value['rid']] = $value['name'];
}

if (user('rid') != 'seo' && user('rid') != 'admin')) { // inverse/negate the logic!
    unset($TabRoles['seo']);
    unset($TabRoles['admin']);
}
```

Comment: I was wondering exactly that before answering, but then, why it doesn't throw an error? It's not a string with an '|' symbol without concatenation?

Comment: How i get the value ?

Comment: In fact none of them worked :) It's by fusion the two of that work! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I'm sorry @DanFromGermany, could you point me where to read about it, I've looked up in php.net > operators and haven't seen anything.

Comment: @Chococroc `|` is an *inclusive (bitwise) or*, see http://php.net/language.operators.bitwise

Comment: @Chococroc youre (both) welcome, sharing knowledge (Y)